# Android Keyboard Hides ExitText field during input

Tags: android, layout

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout>
<Button></Button>    <EditText layout_height=height="fill_parent"> </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

However, the keyboard covers up the EditText so its not good for inputing the value.

Comment: If it was valid you would not see it at all.

Comment: Incorrect.  SO uses special formatting so that you can paste in code and it will show up as is.  Go ahead and try it.